# Edit a cell value with a Form (Appscript in Gsheet)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Good morning,**

I am building a form to handle a database in appscript.

I got some script from a similar past project so I might lack references but I can't find any ... (sorry)

**The functions I already coded are:**

- Create a line in the database
- Search a line in the database
- Select and open a form with the prefilled data of the line

**The function I am trying to code is :**

- Save the edited field in the original column

I am having troubles making this work, I always end up with nothing, no error message, just nothing !

**Data looks like that :**

| ID | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01-1 | 02-1 | 03-1 | 04-1 |
| 02 | 01-2 | 02-2 | 03-2 | 04-2 |
| 03 | 01-3 | 02-3 | 03-3 | 04-3 |
| 04 | 01-4 | 02-4 | 03-4 | 04-4 |

**What I want to see if I EDIT line ID 03 :**

| ID | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01-1 | 02-1 | 03-1 | 04-1 |
| 02 | 01-2 | 02-2 | 03-2 | 04-2 |
| 03 | [EDIT 01-3] | [EDIT 02-3] | [EDIT 03-3] | [EDIT 04-3] |
| 04 | 01-4 | 02-4 | 03-4 | 04-4 |

**And here is my code (simplified version for lisibility):**

*In the HTML Form used for edition*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

  <body>
    <section>
    
    <div>
      <button id="edit" onclick="Edit();Fill()">Edit</button>
    </div>

    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit2(this)">

    <section>

      <div>
        <label for="Field1">Field 1 :</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="Field1Edit" name="Field1Edit"></textarea>
      </div>    
      <div>
        <label for="Field2">Field 2:</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="Field2Edit" name="Field2Edit"></textarea>
      </div>    
      <div>
        <label for="Field3">Field 3:</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="Field3Edit" name="Field3Edit"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="Field4">Field 4 :</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="Field4Edit" name="Field4Edit"></textarea>
      </div>    

    </section>
        
    <div>
      <button id="Submit" onclick="EditVal()">Submit</button>
    </div>

    </form>
    
    <div id="output"></div>

  <script>

  

  /* Trigger form */
  function Edit() {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display='block';
  }

  /* Prefill the fields with their previous values to allow the user to add information in succession */
  function Fill() {    

    var listData2 = JSON.parse(localStorage["Data"]); // Get stored listData

    var Field1 = listData2[1];
    var Field2 = listData2[2];
    var Field3 = listData2[3];
    var Field4 = listData2[4];
    
    document.getElementById("Field1Edit").value = Field1;
    document.getElementById("Field2Edit").value = Field2;
    document.getElementById("Field3Edit").value = Field3;
    document.getElementById("Field4Edit").value = Field4;
    
  }
       
  /* Prevent Form from submitting */
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('Submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
  

  /* Edit Values */   
  function EditVal() {

    document.getElementById("Field1").value = formObject.Field1Edit;
    document.getElementById("Field2").value = formObject.Field2Edit;
    document.getElementById("Field3").value = formObject.Field3Edit;
    document.getElementById("Field4").value = formObject.Field4Edit;

  }
  



  /* Call Process Form 2 and reset the form */  
  function handleFormSubmit2(formObject) {

    google.script.run.processForm2(formObject);
    document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
  }
  
  </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

*And this is the script for "ProcessForm2" :*

```
/* Process Form and replace data in the Sheet */
function processForm2(formObject) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tracker");

  var mylist = [formObject.Field1,formObject.Field2,formObject.Field3,formObject.Field4];
  var cell = 0; /* Start of the range of modified cells */
  
  // Add data after the opening ones in the corresponding row
  for (var i=0; i<mylist.length; i++){
    if ((mylist[i]).length > 0){sheet.getRange(formObject.num,cell).setValue(mylist[i])}
    cell++;
  }  

}
```

**When I submitted the form I just got my fields to reset and nothing happened**

*In my opinion, the issue is located in EditVal() or the order it is trigger.

I tried to trigger it that way too, not working*

```
    <form id="myForm" class="form" onsubmit="EditVal(); handleFormSubmit2(this)">
```

I'd appreciate some help,

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `...addEventListener('submit',...)` not `Submit`

Comment: It is not working, still the same issue. Though why would it be 'submit' ? 

I have : <button id="Submit" onclick="EditVal()">Submit</button>

In my opinion, the issue is located in EditVal() or the order it is trigger. Thank you again for helping me though

Comment: Can you explain how do you select the row to edit?

Comment: @Emel I have a HTML list display that triggers a .click(function) that match on the ID. This part is working, only the edition of a row is not working

Comment: But from what I am seeing this is not in the code you posted, right? Just tested and not seeing that list

Comment: Oh no, It would be too long ! The Output of that search table is going through ListData2[i] - Example : if you click on row 3, ListData[2] will output "02-3", ListData[4] = "04-3" so if you want to test it you can replace by values

Comment: Edited for more accuracy on what I think is the problem

Comment: Your executions tab? Is ProcessForm2 called or not?

Comment: As it is in two different files, I dont know how to see if it gets called. However the form reset so I'm quite sure ProcessForm2 gets called as handleFormSubmit2 is

    google.script.run.processForm2(formObject);
    document.getElementById('myForm').reset();

Comment: Remove the reset and see if it works

Comment: To check executions, [click here](https://script.google.com/home/executions)

Comment: Apparently ProcessForm2 is failing, I get this message : Error Exception: The parameters (null,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange.
    at processForm2(Search:42:39)

Comment: Debug `formObject` to see if it returns what you expect

Comment: @TheMaster Failed also when I remove the reset

Comment: You're sending illegal values in `formObject` or `num` isn't a field in the form.

Comment: You are right ! Num is not a field in the form

Comment: @TheMaster When I delete a field in my form, nothing changes in the database because the Edited field is null, are you aware of what i could add that when I make a field empty, the cell content is deleted (Ex : Field1 = [XXX] Field1Edit = [] )

Comment: Kindly ask a new specific question with [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

### It might be easier

> if you add a field to the database that is called *has_been_edited* and is true or false, then you can just right to that field and test for it to be true. Hope this can help I am not familiar with appscript.

Comment: I am afraid this will be too heavy ... I have more than 100 fields in my full code, so that would mean an additional 100 columns. Moreover the same field could be edited multiple time so we would have a problem. Thank you for the idea though

Answer (score 0):

**Hello,**

**Thank you @TheMaster for the answer,**

*Indeed, I forgot*

```
<input type="hidden" id="num" name="num">
```

*In my form.*

**Thank you @Emel and @Wayne too for your help !**

**Here is the modified code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 

  <body>
    <section>
    
    <div>
      <button id="edit" onclick="Edit();Fill()">Edit</button>
    </div>

    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit2(this)">

    <section>

      <div>
        <label for="Field1">Field 1 :</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="Field1Edit" name="Field1Edit"></textarea>
      </div>    
      <div>
        <label for="Field2">Field 2:</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="Field2Edit" name="Field2Edit"></textarea>
      </div>    
      <div>
        <label for="Field3">Field 3:</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="Field3Edit" name="Field3Edit"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="Field4">Field 4 :</label>
        <textarea type="text" id="Field4Edit" name="Field4Edit"></textarea>
      </div>
    
      <input type="hidden" id="num" name="num">

    </section>
        
    <div>
      <button id="Submit" onclick="alert('Your modification(s) have been taken into account !');">Submit</button>
    </div>

    </form>
    
    <div id="output"></div>

  <script>

  

  /* Trigger form */
  function Edit() {
    document.getElementById('myForm').style.display='block';
  }

  /* Prefill the fields with their previous values to allow the user to add information in succession */
  function Fill() {    

    var listData2 = JSON.parse(localStorage["Data"]); // Get stored listData

    var Field1 = listData2[1];
    var Field2 = listData2[2];
    var Field3 = listData2[3];
    var Field4 = listData2[4];
    
    document.getElementById("Field1Edit").value = Field1;
    document.getElementById("Field2Edit").value = Field2;
    document.getElementById("Field3Edit").value = Field3;
    document.getElementById("Field4Edit").value = Field4;
    
  }
       
  /* Prevent Form from submitting */
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('Submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    

  /* Call Process Form 2 and reset the form */  
  function handleFormSubmit2(formObject) {

    google.script.run.processForm2(formObject);
    document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
  }
  
  </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**And**

```
/* Process Form and replace data in the Sheet */
function processForm2(formObject) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tracker");

  var mylist = [formObject.Field1,formObject.Field2,formObject.Field3,formObject.Field4];
  var cell = 0; /* Start of the range of modified cells */
  
  // Add data after the opening ones in the corresponding row
  for (var i=0; i<mylist.length; i++){
    if ((mylist[i]).length > 0){sheet.getRange(formObject.num,cell).setValue(mylist[i])}
    cell++;
  }  

}
```